# Get Record according to year range

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to select a result from student table-
query -
if I pass any year like 2013 then select the students join start date and end date or he is currently there 
in between these year
like if any student start date year is 2010 and end date year is 2013 
and I select 2011 year then show this student record also .

Table structure is-

```
StudentID   Age startDate   EndDate

1           14  5/05/2013   7/05/2013   
4           17  4/04/2012   8/10/2012
```

and I'm trying this-

```
select * from tblstudent 
Where  DATEPART(year, StartDate) BETWEEN @year-1 AND @year
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i do not understand your question. please phrase your question more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you, but this should do the job:

```
select *
from tblStudent s
where @year >= DATEPART(year, StartDate) and @year <= DATEPART(year, EndDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Actually*, you almost there.

You just need to compare year part of your `StartDate` is smaller or equal to your `@year` **and** year part of your `EndDate` is bigger or equal to your `@year`.

Try like this;

```
select *
from tblStudent
where DATEPART(year, startDate) <= @year and DATEPART(year, EndDate) >= @year
```

For `@year = 2013`, output will be;

```
| STUDENTID | AGE |                  STARTDATE |                     ENDDATE |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |  14 | May, 05 2013 03:00:00+0000 | July, 05 2013 03:00:00+0000 |
```

Here [`SQL Fiddle Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/534e5/8).